# Is there a function to check if a package installed with devtools::install_github has been updated?

Tags: r, devtools

I am the author of a package storred on github. My colleagues install this package with `devtools::install_github()`. They would like to test if the package has been updated or not. Is there a function to check that there has been a commit to the github master branch since they last installed the package?

Answer (score 2):

This is an indirect approach I am aware of 
You can then find your installed version by `packageVersion()`

There's a package available which goes by the name [`versions`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/versions/versions.pdf).
The function `available.versions()` could help you.
This will find you all the package versions ever available.

```
packageVersion("ggplot2")
#[1] ‘1.0.1’

available.versions("ggplot2")

#$ggplot2
#   version       date available
#1    1.0.1 2015-03-17      TRUE
#2    1.0.0 2014-05-21     FALSE
#3  0.9.3.1 2013-03-02     FALSE
...
```

Update:

Package [devtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/devtools.pdf) has functions package_deps() and dev_package_deps().

```
package_deps("ggplot2")

# Needs update -----------------------------
# package      installed available
# ggplot2      2.0.0     2.1.0    
# scales       NA        0.4.0   

?package_deps
"Find all dependencies of a CRAN or dev package."
```

---

*{This function is untested for development package from my end . However I believe this should do your job.}*

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a nice tool. `versions::available.versions()` will "list all of the past versions of the named packages ever uploaded to CRAN". So this will not work with package installed from Github.

Comment: @PaulRougieux added an update. Hope it works out for you. Let me know if not.

Comment: How would you specify the `repo` argument of  `dev_package_deps()` for a github repos? For example for [ggplot2](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2).

Comment: e.g. After you install your package, try
`package_deps("rNVD3", repos = "ramnathv/rNVD3")`

Comment: but  `package_deps("ggplot2", repos = "hadley/ggplot2") ` doesn't check the `"hadley/ggplot2"` repository on github, it just returns  `"Not on CRAN ----"`. While `package_deps("ggplot2") ` tells me the package that need to be updated based on information available on CRAN. What's unclear to me in `?dev_package_deps` is what does a "dev" package mean? I guess it's a package you are developing on your system, not a package hosted on github.

Comment: `package_deps()` is part of the package `remotes`

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I created this function, getting inspired by `devtools::install_github`, that does the job for me. As I understand it it compares the SHA of the installed package and the one on github. I think it requires that the package is installed using devtools::install_github, but haven't tested it extensively enough.

```r
check_github_sha <- function(username, repo, host = "api.github.com") {
  if (Sys.getenv("GITHUB_PAT") == "") {
    stop('Make sure that you have set a "Personal Acess Token" (PAT) named GITHUB_PAT in .Renviron')
  }
  remote_obj <- remote <- list(
    host = host,
    package = NULL,
    repo = repo,
    subdir = NULL,
    username = username,
    ref = "HEAD",
    sha = NULL,
    auth_token = Sys.getenv("GITHUB_PAT")
  )
  remote_obj <- structure(remote_obj, format = format, class = c("github_remote", "remote"))

  remote_sha <- remotes::remote_sha(remote_obj)
  local_sha <- utils::packageDescription(repo, lib.loc = .libPaths())
  if(!"GithubSHA1" %in% names(local_sha)){
    cat(paste0("\033[0;", 33, "m", paste0(repo, "is not installed from github. Probably using build in Rstudio or similar"), "\033[0m", "\n"))
    
  } else {
  
  if (remote_sha != local_sha["GithubSHA1"]) {
    cat(paste0("\033[0;", 31, "m", paste0("NOTE: there is a new version of ", repo, " available"), "\033[0m", "\n"))
  } else {
    cat(paste0("\033[0;", 32, "m", paste0("you have the latest version of ", repo), "\033[0m", "\n"))
  }
  }
}


check_github_sha(username = "username", repo = "repo")
```